# Where should I run scheduled background jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks, background-process, aws-lambda

Here in my company we have our regular application in aws ebs with some background jobs. The problem is, these jobs are starting to get heavier and we were thinking in separate them from the application. The question is: Where should we do it?

We were thinking in doing it in aws lambda, but then we would have to port our rails code to python, node or java, which seems to be a lot of work. What are other options for this? Should we just create another ec2 environment for the jobs? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm using shoryuken gem: http://github.com/phstc/shoryuken integrated with SQS. But its currently with some memory leak and my application is going down sometimes, I dont know if the memory leak is the cause tough. We already separated the application between an API part in EBS and a front-end part in S3.

Comment: Could you check the latest version of Shoryuken? https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v212---2016-12-22 There's a patch for a known memory leak issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, just another EC2 instance with a copy of your Rails app, where instead of `rails s` to start the web server, you run `rake resque:work` or whatever your job runner start command is. Both would share the same Redis instance and database so that your web server writes the jobs to the queue and the worker picks them up and runs them.

If you need more workers, just add more EC2 instances pointing to the same Redis instance. I would advise separating your jobs by queue name, so that one worker can just process fast stuff e.g. email sending, and others can do long running or slow jobs.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to say in the question. I'm using shoryuken gem: https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken integrated with SQS. But its currently with some memory leak and my application is going down sometimes, I dont know if the memory leak is the cause tough.

Comment: We already separated the application in a API part located in EBS, and a front-end part in S3...

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar requirement, for us it was the sidekiq background jobs,  they started to get very heavy, so we split it into a separate opsworks stack, with a simple recipe to build the machine dependencies ( ruby, mysql, etc ), and since we don't have to worry about load balancers and requests timing out, it's ok for all machines to deploy at the same time.

Also another thing you could use in opsworks is using scheduled machines ( if the jobs are needed at certain times during the day ), having the machine get provisioned few minutes before the time of the task, and then after the task is done you could make it shutdown automatically, that would reduce your cost.

EB also has a different type of application, which is the worker application, you could also check that out, but honestly I haven't looked into it so I can't tell you what are the pros and cons of that.

Answer (score 1):

We recently passed on that route. I dockerized our rails app, and wrote a custom entrypoint to that docker container. In summary that entrypoint parses commands after you run `docker run IMAGE_NAME`

For example: If you run: `docker run IMAGE_NAME sb rake do-something-magical` entrypoint understands that it will run rake job with sandbox envrionment config. if you only run: `docker run IMAGE_NAME` it will do `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

PS: I wrote custom entrypoint because we have 3 different environments, that entrypoint downloads environment specific config from s3.

And I set up an ECS Cluster, wrote an task-runner job on Lambda this lambda function schedules a task on ecs cluster, and we trigger that lambda from CloudWatch Events. You can send custom payloads to lambda when using CloudWatch Events.

It sounds complicated but implementation is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to submit your task to AWS SQS services, then you may use elasticbeantaslk worker enviroment to process your backgrown task.

Elasticbeanstalk supports rail application:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of work these background jobs perform, you might want to think about maybe extracting those functions into microservices if you are running your jobs on a difference instance anyway.

[Here](https://blog.codeship.com/architecting-rails-apps-as-microservices/) is a good codeship blog post on how to approach this.

For simple mailer type stuff, this definitely feels a little heavy handed, but if the functionality is more complex, e.g. general notification of different clients, it might well be worth the overhead.